# Is it possible to use a variable in systemd mount unit configuration?

Tags: systemd

Is it possible to use a variable in the `what=` field of a systemd mount configuration file instead of an absolute path string?

For Example:

```
[Unit]
Before=local-fs.target

[Mount]
What=/dev/disk/by-partlabel/${part_variable}
Where=/mnt/optional/config/
```

I am trying to find a way to use a custom kernel command-line bootparam, and mount a partition provided by that bootparam.

Answer (score 6):

For the record:

> Is if possible to use a variable in the `What=` field of a systemd mount
>   configuration file instead of an absolute path string?

Yes, it is possible, e.g. (just tested with `systemd v.238`):

`mnt-data.mount` content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount System Backups Directory

[Mount]
What=${SOMEPATH}
Where=/mnt/data
Type=ext4
Options=defaults
```

if you run

```
systemctl set-environment SOMEPATH=/dev/disk/by-label/DATA
```

and then

```
systemctl start mnt-date.mount
```

it will mount `/dev/disk/by-label/DATA` to `/mnt/data`

or, via a env file:

`mnt-data.mount` content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount System Backups Directory

[Mount]
EnvironmentFile=/path/to/env_file
What=${SOMEPATH}
Where=/mnt/data
Type=ext4
Options=defaults
```

`/path/to/env_file` content:

```
SOMEPATH=/dev/disk/by-uuid/1b5a38ca-9f0d-4f1a-8fc1-7c418e79bf07
```

This may not help you to

> find a way to use a custom kernel command-line
>   bootparam, and mount a partition provided by that bootparam.

but it's definitely possible to use `What=${SOMEVAR}`.

Answer (score 1):

According to `man systemd.mount`, no variable substitution is supported there.

I believe it's still possible to write a systemd service which runs early in the boot process, which writes out a a dynamically generated `.mount` file.

Answer (score 0):

No.

What you describe is exactly what generators are for, see `man systemd.generators`.  Compare `man systemd-fstab-generator` which generates the mount units from `/etc/fstab`, it also reads e.g. `root=` from the kernel command line.  That said, if you only support a kernel command line option, and you don't have a config file, you may be just as happy writing an early-boot (`DefaultDependencies=no`) service unit for this.